# Radgrid multiple detail tables at a level, IE 9 Compatibility View rows stacking

Tags: cross-browser, telerik, internet-explorer-9, telerik-grid, radgrid

I have a radgrid which have 3 detail tables in same level.

It works **fine with IE 9**, but when I changed to **compatibility mode** all 3 detail tables shows up at the same place, text stacking over. And only last detail tables header showing.

For example: **Caption and rows stacking**:

[image: caption and row texts stacking]

What can I do to resolve this issue? This page has to support both IE 9 and IE 9 Compatibility Mode.

Is there anything like detail table order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue.

It was because the following property. I removed it and grid appeared as expected.

```
RadGrid1.HorizontalAlign="Right";
```